# Use AWS cognitos multi factor authentication in custom functions

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Im developing a serverless application using the following technologies:

- Angular2 with the AWS SDK for frontend
- AWS Cognito
- AWS S3
- AWS Lambda
- AWS DynamoDB
- AWS API gateway

**Question:** Is it possbile to use cognito MFA (multi factor authentication) in my own frontend functions?

**Use case:** If an authenticated user request to delete a file from their S3 bucket, a SMS is send to the user's mobile phone, and the user will input the security code into the frontend. If the security code is valid the file(s) are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the MFA is only for log in... However, you can generate a code that you send by SMS with AWS SNS. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SMSMessages.html